# Not getting correct coloring of Red Black Tree nodes

Tags: c++, class, red-black-tree

I have finally figured out how to successfully insert items into my red black tree without getting any segmentation faults, however, my coloring of my nodes are off.

I am trying to insert the following values into the tree in the following order: `4 3 2 6 5 1`

When I go to print out the tree InOrder I get the following: `1-R  2-B  3-B 
 4-R  5-R  6-B`

When I should be getting: `1-R  2-B  3-B  4-R  5-B  6-R`

Here is my `InsertFixUp` function:

```
void RBTree::RBInsertFixUp(RBNode* z){
RBNode* y;

if(z == RBTree::root){
    root->color = 'B';
}else{
    while(z->parent->color == 'R'){
        if(z->parent == z->parent->parent->left){
            y = z->parent->parent->right;


        if(y->color == 'R'){
            z->parent->color = 'B';                 //Case 1 Check
            y->color = 'B';                         //Case 1 Check
            z->parent->parent->color = 'R';         //Case 1 Check
            z = z->parent->parent;                  //Case 1 
        }else{

                if(z == z->parent->right){
                    z = z->parent;                  //Case 2
                    RBLeftRotate(z);                //Case 2 Look at Rotate
                }
                z->parent->color = 'B';             //Case 3 Check
                z->parent->parent->color = 'R';     //Case 3 Check
                RBRightRotate(z->parent->parent);   //Case 3 Look at Rotate
            }
        }else{
            y = z->parent->parent->left;

            if(y->color = 'R'){                     
                z->parent->color = 'B';             //Case 1 Check
                y->color = 'B';                     //Case 1 Check
                z->parent->parent->color = 'R';     //Case 1 Check
                z = z->parent->parent;              //Case 1  

            }else{

                if(z = z->parent->left){
                    z = z->parent;                  //Case 2
                    RBRightRotate(z);               //Case 2 Look at Rotate
                }
                z->parent->color = 'B';             //Case 3 Check
                z->parent->parent->color = 'R';     //Case 3 Check 
                RBLeftRotate(z->parent->parent);    //Case 3 Look at Rotate
            }
        }
    }

    root->color = 'B';
}
```

and here are my Left and Right Rotates:

```
void RBTree::RBLeftRotate(RBNode* x){
    RBNode* y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;
    y->left->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;

    if(x->parent == RBTree::Tnil){
        root = y;
    }else if(x == x->parent->left){
        x->parent->left = y;
    }else{
        x->parent->right = y;
    }

    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;
}

void RBTree::RBRightRotate(RBNode* x){
    RBNode* y = x->left;
    x->left = y->right;
    y->right->parent = x;
    y->parent = x->parent;

    if(x->parent == RBTree::Tnil){
        root = y;
    }else if(x == x->parent->right){
        x->parent->right = y;
    }else{
        x->parent->left = y;
    }
    y->right = x;
    x->parent = y;
}
```

From everything that I can see, my coloring is right and my rotates are too, but maybe I'm missing something. Any help as to why my coloring would be off would be great.

Comment: _From everything I can see_ - but what did you look at? Did you step through an insertion and watch every assignment? Or add logging? You have to make some effort to debug the code, not just eyeball the source and say "it looks right".

Answer (score 0):

In the second rotation for the non-red-uncle path (her from the z->parent is left child branch):

```
RBRightRotate(z->parent->parent);   //Case 3 Look at Rotate
```

You are rotating at the grandparent node but z has already been moved up one level if z and z->parent have different orientations.

I suggest making the entire non-red-uncle path the following (the parent-is-right-child path is left for you):

```
if(z == z->parent->right)
        RBLeftRotate(z->parent);
    else
        z = z->parent;

    z->color = 'B';
    z->parent->color = 'R';
    RBRightRotate(z->parent);
```